# Mock of IBinder fails when unit testing Activity Function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to test an activity function which has the following definition:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(LoadReferenceFromBlobStorage))]
public static async Task<string> Run([ActivityTrigger] string blobName,
    IBinder binder,
    ILogger log)
{
    StorageAccountAttribute storageAccountAtt = new StorageAccountAttribute("AzureWebJobsStorage");
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = await binder.BindAsync<CloudStorageAccount>(storageAccountAtt, CancellationToken.None);
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    //...
}
```

I mock the `IBinder` in the unit test as:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetReference()
{
    var attribute = new StorageAccountAttribute("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;");
    var mock = new Mock<IBinder>();
    CloudStorageAccount mockedResult = null;
    CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;", out mockedResult);
    mock.Setup(x => x.BindAsync<CloudStorageAccount>(attribute, CancellationToken.None))
            .ReturnsAsync(mockedResult);

    ILogger logger = NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger("log");
    var res = await LoadReferenceFromBlobStorage.Run("name", mock.Object, logger);

    //...
}
```

The test calls the activity successfully but the result of `binder.BindAsync` is always *null*.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two separate instances in the setup and what is actually invoked in the test.

The method under test is creating its own instance of `StorageAccountAttribute` with a hard-coded `"AzureWebJobsStorage"`, while the test is using another instance for the setup expression. Those will not match when exercising the test and thus the mock will return *null* as experienced.

Try to loosen the setup by using `It.IsAny<T>()` is the expectation expression.

```
//Arrange    
CloudStorageAccount mockedResult = null;
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;", out mockedResult);

var mock = new Mock<IBinder>();
mock
    .Setup(x => x.BindAsync<CloudStorageAccount>(It.IsAny<StorageAccountAttribute>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(mockedResult);

ILogger logger = Mock.Of<ILogger>();
//Act
var res = await LoadReferenceFromBlobStorage.Run("name", mock.Object, logger);

//Assert

//...
```

That will allow

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = await binder.BindAsync<CloudStorageAccount>(storageAccountAtt, CancellationToken.None);
```

to behave as expected when invoked.

Concerning the `StorageAccountAttribute` hard-coded argument you may want to also consider refactoring that so it can be replaced when testing so as not to have issues with the storage being used when testing.